# bxslider move first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

How to make first bxslider slide to move -26px to left? I find out this line in slider:

```
propValue = slider.settings.mode === 'vertical' ? 'translate3d(0, ' + value + 'px, 0)' : 'translate3d(' + value + 'px, 0, 0)';
```

so I could change `'translate3d(' + value + 'px, 0, 0)'` to `'translate3d(' + (value - 26) + 'px, 0, 0)'`

and it would work, but the problem is, that I'm using several slides with different params and I can't modify this script. So how make it to move first slide by -26px to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried a little bit and try it and let me know and

when you initialize, do like below

```
  $('.home .bxslider').bxSlider({
    initLeftVal: 20
  });


    //first, add extra property to defautls
    var defaults = {
        initLeftVal: 0;
    }

    //check for this function and replace whole function( dont replace just comment out)
    var setSlidePosition = function(){
        var initLeftVal = slider.settings.initLeftVal;
        // if last slide, not infinite loop, and number of children is larger than specified maxSlides
        if(slider.children.length > slider.settings.maxSlides && slider.active.last && !slider.settings.infiniteLoop){
            if (slider.settings.mode == 'horizontal'){
                // get the last child's position
                var lastChild = slider.children.last();
                var position = lastChild.position();
                // set the left position
                setPositionProperty(-(position.left + initLeftVal - (slider.viewport.width() - lastChild.outerWidth())), 'reset', 0);
            }else if(slider.settings.mode == 'vertical'){
                // get the last showing index's position
                var lastShowingIndex = slider.children.length - slider.settings.minSlides;
                var position = slider.children.eq(lastShowingIndex).position();
                // set the top position
                setPositionProperty(-(position.top+initLeftVal), 'reset', 0);
            }
        // if not last slide
        }else{
            // get the position of the first showing slide
            var position = slider.children.eq(slider.active.index * getMoveBy()).position();
            // check for last slide
            if (slider.active.index == getPagerQty() - 1) slider.active.last = true;
            // set the repective position
            if (position != undefined){
                if (slider.settings.mode == 'horizontal') setPositionProperty(-(position.left+initLeftVal), 'reset', 0);
                else if (slider.settings.mode == 'vertical') setPositionProperty(-(position.top+initLeftVal), 'reset', 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it looks nice, but I don't get one thing - where insert the function? Becouse there is no function like "setSlidePosition" on my bxslider

Comment: oh, I see now and its helpfull a lot :) its working!!